# Image slider in a theme not showing in magento

Tags: magento

I installed a new theme which contain image silder through magento connect and change the design to new theme.The theme is coming but image slider part is not getting.What is the solution.Please help me.

Comment: Check theme documentation . may be you need to assign slider block in CMS page .. or set images name from system configuration

Comment: In that documentation they are telling that enable following functions and modules: admin-side-manageable banner slider on home page, horizontal product/categories menu, newsletter sign-up block, most popular block, home page products, shopping cart side-bar, customer service block, up-sells and cross-sells. But I don't know how to enable it??

Comment: @PankajPareek Can you please help me to enable this functions?